# On which object is pointing "this"?

Tags: java, swing, this

i'm making my first experiences with java swing and also in general java. Might anyone tell me on which Object "this.button1"(e.g.) is pointing? Is there a possibility to replace "this"? I already read that "this" is pointing an the actual object, but which one is it in this context?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;


public class BeispielListener extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JButton button1;
JButton button2;
JButton button3;
JLabel label;
JPanel panel;

public BeispielListener(){
    this.setTitle("ActionListener Beispiel");
    this.setSize(400, 200);
    panel = new JPanel();

    // Leeres JLabel-Objekt wird erzeugt
    label = new JLabel();

    //Drei Buttons werden erstellt
    button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
    button2 = new JButton ("Button 2");
    button3 = new JButton ("Button 3");

    //Buttons werden dem Listener zugeordnet
    button1.addActionListener(this);
    button2.addActionListener(this);
    button3.addActionListener(this);

    //Buttons werden dem JPanel hinzugefügt
    panel.add(button1);
    panel.add(button2);
    panel.add(button3);

    //JLabel wird dem Panel hinzugefügt
    panel.add(label);
    this.add(panel);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Ein neues Objekt der Klasse BeispielListener wird erzeugt
    // und sichtbar gemacht
    BeispielListener bl = new BeispielListener();
    bl.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae){
    // Die Quelle wird mit getSource() abgefragt und mit den
    // Buttons abgeglichen. Wenn die Quelle des ActionEvents einer
    // der Buttons ist, wird der Text des JLabels entsprechend geändert
    if(ae.getSource() == this.button1){
        label.setText(("Button 1 wurde betätigt"));
    }
    else if(ae.getSource() == this.button2){
        label.setText("Button 2 wurde betätigt");
    }
    else if (ae.getSource() == this.button3){
        label.setText(("Button 3 wurde betätigt"));
    }
}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: "this" points to current object

Answer (score 1):

`this` points to the current object you are working with. Therefore, in your code it is pointing to the `BeispielListener` instance.

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using this.

Here `this.button1` is refenrecing the `button1` variable of the current class

read the full doc and you will get a clear concept.

Answer (score 0):

In Java `this` is nothing but a reference of your current object on which you are working. Here in this case it is a reference of `BeispielListener`.